# How to get ranges of spreadsheets after applying filter in google sheets API?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I have one google spreadsheet. I use python script and google sheets python api to manipulate my sheet. I first set the basic filter on my google sheet using `setBasicFilterRequest` like this :

```py
setBasicFilterRequest = {
    'setBasicFilter' : {
        'filter' : _filter
    }
}

body = { 
    'requests' : [setBasicFilterRequest],
}

resp = service.spreadsheets() \
   .batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, body=body).execute()
```

This sets a filter on my spreadsheet, and when I see it on browser, I see only filtered rows. This is great. Now in this script, I want to get the ranges which are currently visible on the sheet on my browser. For example, when I set my basic filter, the google sheet view is updated to only show filtered rows, and I see rows `[2, 11, 27, 31, 55]`. Now, I want to fetch this list in my python script. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike, I'm extremely sorry for not replying for a while. Actually I got sick and did not get a time to test this. I tested this and this is perfectly correct, exactly what I wanted. I again apologise.  You did very much for me, but apparently, I don't deserve any help. I'm sorry again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's no problem. And thank you for testing my answer. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the row numbers of the filtered rows in a sheet.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.

#### Issue and workaround:

In this case, unfortunately, the row numbers cannot be directly retrieved from Sheets API. So it is required to do the following flow.

1. Retrieve `rowMetadata` of the sheet using the method of "spreadsheets.get" in Sheets API.
2. Retrieve the filtered rows from the value of `rowMetadata` using a script.

When this flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, please use your authorization script for `creds` of `credentials=creds`.

```
spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name.

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
fields = 'sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByFilter)))'
res = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=sheetName, fields=fields).execute()
filteredRows = {"shownRows": [], "hiddenRows": []}
rowMetadata = res["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowMetadata"]
for i, r in enumerate(rowMetadata):
    filteredRows["hiddenRows" if "hiddenByFilter" in r and r["hiddenByFilter"] else "shownRows"].append(i + 1)
print(filteredRows)
```

- In this script, `sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByFilter)))` is used as `fields`.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained.

```
{
  "shownRows": [#, #, #,,,],
  "hiddenRows": [#, #, #,,,]
}
```

- `shownRows` is the shown row numbers by the basic filter.
- `hiddenRows` is the hidden row numbers by the basic filter.

#### Note:

- From [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66767685), I thought that you have already known about the method using Query Language. So in this answer, I introduced the method using Sheets API.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)