# Fetching only the non-hidden, visible data of a Google spreadsheet using Python and Google Sheets API?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Sheets API to retrieve data from online spreadsheets and to read them into a pandas dataframe. I have successfully set up the script to fetch the data but this default implementation fetches everything, even hidden rows/columns. There are many rows on the spreadsheet that have been hidden. I do not want to retrieve those, as the hidden state of a row means it is irrelevant. Therefore, I am looking for an approach to fetch a spreadsheet **without the manually hidden rows/columns**. Or, alternatively, an approach to fetch a spreadsheet content and **exclude the hidden cells** afterwards. So far I haven't managed to figure out whether such a feature is implemented in the Google Sheets API.

My current, working implementation is as follows. The problem here is that this includes even hidden rows/columns:

```
def getSpreadsheetData(name, spreadsheet_id, sheet_id=None):

    global values_input, service
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(creds_file_path, SCOPES)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    data_table = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
                                      range=name).execute()
    data_values = data_table.get('values', [])

    if not data_values:
        print('No data found.')
        return -1

    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_values)
        return df
```

**Edit:**
This problem, in my opinion, is different from merely filtering the spreadsheet based on a column value, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767685/how-to-get-only-filtered-rows-from-google-sheets-to-python-script-using-google-a). I want to fetch only those rows of a spreadsheet that are not hidden. The default API call to fetch content of a spreadsheet (see my code above) fetches all the rows, even those that have manually been hidden and hence are not visible for people opening the spreadsheet via a link.

**Edit 2:**
I updated the post to make it more clear that my current working implementation returns all hidden cells and this is exactly what I do not want. I want an approach that can exclude those rows/columns that have manually been hidden by a user, as hidden cells are unimportant and irrelevant. Hence, I do not need them in my output dataframe.

**Edit 3:**
I put together a small sample dataset shared below. Please copy the content to a Google Sheet. With this data, I found that the parser doesn't manage to distinguish what is supposed to be header and what is supposed to be in the first row. Note that the sample dataset has three visible rows and one hidden row. The function is required to return these three visible rows in a pandas dataframe. Instead, I get one header and two rows only, where the header is actually a combination of the true column names and the first row content.
*Dataset*:

```
Lesson  Date/Time       German        English                   Completed
Hallo!  Oct 21st, 2021  nicht         not   
Hallo!  Oct 21st, 2021  nicht so gut  not so good               10/22
Hallo!  Oct 21st, 2021  oder          or    
Hallo!  Oct 21st, 2021  schön         nice; beautiful; pretty   10/22
```

Note: row 3 (the one containing 'oder' and 'or') was hidden.

*Code*:

```
def getSpreadsheetData(spreadsheet_id, sheet_id=None):

    global values_input, service
    creds_file_path = ""        # add your service account path here 
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(creds_file_path, SCOPES)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    access_token = creds.get_access_token().access_token

    url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet_id + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + sheet_id
    res = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token})
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.text), sep=',')
    return df
```

*Incorrect output:*

```
  Lesson Hallo! Date/Time Oct 21st, 2021  German nicht              English not Completed   Unnamed: 5
0        Hallo!           Oct 21st, 2021  nicht so gut              not so good      10/22         NaN
1        Hallo!           Oct 21st, 2021         schön  nice; beautiful; pretty      10/22         NaN
```

As it can be seen, the header and first row is combined, which is incorrect. Including the `header=0` parameter in `pd.read_csv()` didn't help either, same incorrect output is returned.

---

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767685/how-to-get-only-filtered-rows-from-google-sheets-to-python-script-using-google-a)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get only filtered rows from google sheets to python script using google API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767685/how-to-get-only-filtered-rows-from-google-sheets-to-python-script-using-google-a)

Comment: @HampusLarsson and @Carlos M thank you for your suggestions. I had a look but it is very unclear how that would be applicable to my problem. If I understand correctly, the referenced question is about filtering a spreadsheet using a column value, i.e. returning only those rows of the original spreadsheet where column `A` is `open`. This is a very different problem from what I have: returning only the *visible* rows of a spreadsheet.

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your goal of `I want to fetch only those rows of a spreadsheet that are not hidden.`, in this case, you want to retrieve the showing row values from a sheet with the manually hidden rows (this is not the basic filter) in a Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your following goal,

> This problem, in my opinion, is different from merely filtering the spreadsheet based on a column value, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767685/how-to-get-only-filtered-rows-from-google-sheets-to-python-script-using-google-a). I want to fetch only those rows of a spreadsheet that are not hidden. The default API call to fetch content of a spreadsheet (see my code above) fetches all the rows, even those that have manually been hidden and hence are not visible for people opening the spreadsheet via a link.

My sample script retrieves the showing rows from the sheet with the hidden rows using Query Language. So, about `I want to fetch only those rows of a spreadsheet that are not hidden.`, this can be achieved by the sample script. From `The default API call to fetch content of a spreadsheet (see my code above) fetches all the rows, even those that have manually been hidden and hence are not visible for people opening the spreadsheet via a link.`, I thought that you have tried to use Sheets API. In this case, all rows are retrieved even when the hidded rows are existing.

And from `read them into a pandas dataframe.`, I thought that your goal can be achieved by modifying the sample script of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66774086/7108653).

So, in order to achieve your goal, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

#### Sample script:

```py
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds) # This is from your script.

spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_id = "###"  # Please set the sheet name.

# Removed ---> url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet_id + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + sheet_id
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet_id + '/pub?output=csv&gid=' + sheet_id
res = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + creds.token})
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.text), sep=',')
```

- In this sample, `import csv`, `import io` and `import requests` are also used. And, the access token is retrieved from `creds` of `service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)`.
- When this script is run, the showing rows are retrieved from the sheet with the hidden rows, and the retrieved values are put in the dataframe.

  - In this sample script, the script for putting the retrieved values to the dataframe is added to [the script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66774086/7108653).
- In this method, the showing rows can be retrieved from not only the sheet with the manually hidden rows but also the sheet with the filtered rows by the basic filter.

#### Reference:

- [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

### Added 1:

When the above script couldn't resolve your issue, please test the following script. In this script, the values are retrieved with Sheets API. At that time, at first, the row numbers filtered by the basic filter are retrieved. And, using the row numbers, the showing rows are retrieved.

#### Sample script:

```py
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds) # This is from your script.

spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = "Sheet1"  # Please set the sheet name.

fields = 'sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByFilter)))'
res = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=sheet_name, fields=fields).execute()
rowMetadata = res["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowMetadata"]
filteredRows = {"shownRows": [], "hiddenRows": []}
for i, r in enumerate(rowMetadata):
    filteredRows["hiddenRows" if "hiddenByFilter" in r and r["hiddenByFilter"] else "shownRows"].append(i + 1)

result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=sheet_name).execute()
values = result.get("values", [])
v = []
for e in filteredRows["shownRows"]:
    if e - 1 < len(values):
        v.append(values[e - 1])
    else:
        break
df = pd.DataFrame(v[1:], columns=v[0])
print(df)
```

### Added 2:

When the rows are hidded by the basic filter and the manual operation, you can retrieve the showing rows using the following script.

#### Sample script:

```py
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds) # This is from your script.

spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = "Sheet1"  # Please set the sheet name.

fields = 'sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByFilter,hiddenByUser)))'
res = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=sheet_name, fields=fields).execute()
rowMetadata = res["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowMetadata"]
filteredRows = {"shownRows": [], "hiddenRows": []}
for i, r in enumerate(rowMetadata):
    filteredRows["hiddenRows" if ("hiddenByFilter" in r and r["hiddenByFilter"]) or ("hiddenByUser" in r and r["hiddenByUser"]) else "shownRows"].append(i + 1)

result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=sheet_name).execute()
values = result.get("values", [])
v = []
for e in filteredRows["shownRows"]:
    if e - 1 < len(values):
        v.append(values[e - 1])
    else:
        break
df = pd.DataFrame(v[1:], columns=v[0])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Tanaike. Two remarks:
1. I noticed that `creds.token` returned an error, hence I needed to use `creds.get_access_token().access_token` to pass the token instead.
2. Are you sure this approach returns the entire content? I am on Windows and `res.text` seems to only contain a tiny portion of the original spreadsheet content.

Comment: @lazarea Thank you for replying. About `Are you sure this approach returns the entire content?`, this method retrieves the showing rows from the sheet with the hidden rows, and the retrieved values. I apologize for this. About `I am on Windows and res.text seems to only contain a tiny portion of the original spreadsheet content.`, from `I want to fetch only those rows of a spreadsheet that are not hidden.` in your question, I thought that you wanted to retrieve the showing rows from the sheet with the hidden rows, and the retrieved values. If my understanding is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: My problem is the following: sheets often have manually hidden rows. I want to retrieve content of a sheet EXCLUDING the rows that are hidden. The default implementation that I shared in my original post doesn't differentiate between non-hidden (visible) and hidden (invisible) rows. In other words: the default implementation fetches ALL rows, even the hidden ones. I do not want the hidden rows, only the rows that I and other users can see.

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I updated the original post again!

Comment: @lazarea Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, about `I want to retrieve content of a sheet EXCLUDING the rows that are hidden.`, my proposed script can achieve this. When I tested my proposed script, only showing rows from the sheet including the hidden rows can be retrieved. So I cannot understand your current issue. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I experimented a bit and put together a sample dataset that demonstrates the core issue I am experiencing. The hidden rows are not returned indeed (correctly!), but there is a different problem: the parser doesn't distinguish the header/column names from the first row, hence melting the two together. I edited my main post again.

Comment: @lazarea Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that your question of `I want to retrieve content of a sheet EXCLUDING the rows that are hidden.` has been resolved. I'm glad about it. About your updated question, unfortunately, I cannot open your sample Spreadsheet. So I cannot see your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. Can you confirm it again? And also, from `Incorrect output:`, I can see the "Incorrect output:". But I cannot know your expected result. I apologize for this. Can you also provide your expected result? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I copied the example dataset and added it to the original post. It has 4 rows, row number 3 is to be hidden, and the header row is set to frozen on the Google Sheet. When running the function to read the data into a pandas dataframe, the above mentioned incorrect output is produced: header and first row get combined, very incorrectly. I tried manually specifying column names as well, and tinkering with the `header` argument of `read_csv`, but none seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: @lazarea Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I thought that I could understand your current issue. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? In this case, I changed the value of `url`. If this was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize again.

Comment: @lazarea When the above script couldn't resolve your issue, please test the added script. If those were not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @lazarea Now, I added one more sample script. In that script, the showing rows are retrieved from the sheet with the hidden rows with the basic filter and the manual operation.

Comment: sorry for getting back to you so late. I have gone through your additional code suggestions and implemented them and I can say it works perfectly now. I am only getting the actually visible rows, and column names are not messed up any more either. Thank you immensely for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @lazarea Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.